# How to share application settings between repos

Tags: git, github, repository, application-settings

I have troubles to find a good solution for sharing application settings between repos on git. 
The situation is something like this:

There are 2 repos (*not branches*):

- `process` = contains specific data processing with output into public folder accessible by `design`
- `design` = web UI, access to data processed by `process`

There are 2 developers:

- `back-end developer` = has access to `process` repo only
- `front-end developer` = has access to `design` repo only

There are application settings for each of them. Some of the settings are shared. Like the path to `public folder`. *In reality there are more of them, I just want to keep it simple.*

Now, `back-end developer` changes the path to the `public folder`, commits and push changes to `process` repo.
And my problem and question: How do I update the path to `public folder` in the `design` repo?

So far, the best I could find, is to create additional repository `settings`. This repository is then added as submodule to both `process` and `design`. So when front-end developer run `fetch` or `pull` the path is updated. 
However, I don't like adding the new repository just for settings, and was wondering if there is some other better approach or concept that I could use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think creating a new repository is a good option, you could write an script to synchronise these files. For instance, something that would let you choose source and target repositories and copy a list of determined files from one to the other. If instead of full files you only need to update certain lines the script complexity would be a little bit higher but not too much. The thing here is that every time settings are changed and pushed from design, this script would need to be run in the process side.
This process could be automated with tools such as [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/), you could create a Jenkins job to run a script every time code is pushed into one repository to copy and push the necessary information to the other repo.  However, tools like Jenkins are mainly for continuous integration purposes, so you might end up with a rather complex scenario to solve your problem.